# Using a static view inside of an override function

Tags: swift, struct

I have a variable inside a swift file for a custom segment control. Here is where it is

```
open override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if !isConfigurated {
        configureItemsConent()
        configureViewBounds()

        configureContainerView()
        configureItems()
        configureSelectedView()
        configureSelectedLabelsView()
        configureSelectedLabelItems()

        isConfigurated = true
    }

    containerView.frame = bounds
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius < 0 ? 0.5 * containerView.frame.size.height : cornerRadius
    selectedLabelsView.frame = containerView.bounds

    updateFrameForLables(allItemLabels)
    updateFrameForLables(allSelectedItemLabels)
    updateSelectedViewFrame()

    selectItemAt(index:currentSelectedIndex)
    _ = self.subviews.map({$0.isExclusiveTouch = true})

    var selectedIndex: Int = currentSelectedIndex 
}
```

I need to access the variable `selectedIndex` from inside my view controller where the segment controller is. It's inside the view controller `newSavingsViewController`. I already tried a struct, and it would work if I could call the variable outside of the function, so anyway I can call it in the view controller or outside the function that would help.

Comment: Why do you need to access the local variable `selectedIndex`? Why doesn't your custom control provide a `selectedSegmentIndex` property like `UISegmentedControl`?

Comment: @rmaddy It does and I’ve tried that but because it’s a custom view I can’t find a way to detect which index it’s on besides this way. Unless if you want me to share all of my custom segment code. It just creates sub views.

Comment: What is `currentSelectedIndex` and how is it set? Why not just access that?

Comment: @rmaddy That’s what I’m trying to do. I just need to find a way to access it in my view controller. That’s what I need help with.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but never use `map` simply for side effects if you are discarding the return value. Use `forEach` in this case instead: `self.subviews.forEach({$0.isExclusiveTouch = true})`

Comment: @DávidPásztor ok thanks. Back to my original question is there a way I could call my variable in my view controller?